# Getting console error from Facebook JS SDK

Tags: console, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm getting this console error from Facebook SDK.js

> FB.NativeExtensions.onready only works when the page is rendered in a WebView of the native Facebook app. Test if this is the case calling FB.UA.nativeApp()

Using [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com/) plugin for social sharing on the website. Is anyone facing this issue before?

Comment: Yes, I have this same error message. Everything seems to work though

Comment: Same console error here. Seems to be quite new.

Comment: it's a facebook bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1514160572216577/